# Peticion http en c#

Tags: c#, json, http

Hola estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion en C# relacionado con un juego. El problema que tengo es el siguiente es que cuando hago lo siguiente siempre me muestra la excepcion:

```
try
{
    string response = await _client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(Config.USER_REQUEST_FORMAT, Username));
    User user = User.fromJSON(response);
    UpdateInfo(user);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to the habbo API, this is most likely because the username you specified does not exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

la string del enlace es la siguiente:

```
public static string USER_REQUEST_FORMAT = "https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name={0}";
```

por ejemplo este un ejemplo del resultado que me devolvera
https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=omar

pero cuando intento conseguir este json me salta la excepcion

Comment: ¿Cuál excepción? Por favor comparte el mensaje de error exacto así como el stack trace completo. Lo ideal es que arregles el código de forma que sea [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok modificare el codigo poniendo la parte principal un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable. y el error es que cuando hagof romJSON(response) me salta la excepcion siempre.

Comment: Deberías también agregar el código de User.fromJSON(string response) y el de UpdateInfo(User user), pues en esto puede estar el error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que este sitio requiere que en la cabecera HTTP se establezca un valor para UserAgent. Si se comenta la línea 4 de este código la respuesta es un 463. Si se agrega UserAgent la respuesta es 200.

```
string page = "https://www.habbo.com/api/public/users?name=omar";
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Fiddler");
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (result != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mi recomendación es que uses la librería de Json.net pues te encapsula mucho de los procesos para realizar peticiones. A continuación un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer con esa librería:

```
static void ExampleHabbo(string username)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://www.habbo.com/api/public");
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.GET;
        request.Resource = "users";
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddQueryParameter("name", username);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
            Dictionary<string, object> result = deserial.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(response);
        }
    }
```

Llamas a ese método le pasas el nombre y te devuelve el json con sus propiedades.
En esta imagen se ve el diccionario que puse para que se guardaran los objetos :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Isra, ¿podrías añadir link a documentación? ¿Y algún ejemplo? Tal y cómo está la respuesta luce cómo comentario D:

Comment: Mis disculpas, escribí antes de salir para casa y no me dio tiempo poner la respuesta con el RestSharp. Gracias.